# Postgres quoted macro syntax error

Tags: postgresql, psql

Attempting to use a quoted psql SET value:

```
 $ psql db_name -v x=y
 => select :x;
 ERROR: column "y" does not exist # this is correct and expected
  => select UPPER(:'x');
 ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
 LINE 1: select UPPER(:'x');
```

that last query should return

```
  upper
----------
 Y
(1 row)
```

but doesn't on one box but not another? (Not sure what this kind of SET value use is referred to as).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my client version was old:

```
# psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 8.4.20
contains support for command-line editing
```

Needed a 9.x client version.  Pesky old distros :\